# Replace objective-c file with swift file, problem occurred in briding-header.h file and can't find myprojec-swift.h file

Tags: objective-c, swift4

First i should inform you that my project is built on both objc-c and swift file and project name is “myproject” no space in my project name. I am using both swift class inside objc-c  class and objc-c class inside swift class and also inherit those class one another, thats is swift inherit objc-c and objc-c inherit swift class(obviously bad practice).

For this reason i need to use both myproject-bridging-Header.h and myproject-swift.h

I am trying to convert my objective-c class with swift class. My procedure look like-

A.h, A.m will be replace by A.swift. This A.h class was previously inherited by C.h class.

My problem is, whenever i replace my objc-c file by removing A.h, A.m and adding A.swift file in my project show briding-Header.h file error, but this error is omitted by - "clean build folder" and delete "derive data" and rebuild project.

Then the actual issue arise, that is myproject-swift.h file is missing from my project.

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to import the Swift file (what you have on the .h and .m files)?

Comment: In my .h file `@interface A : NSObject` and .m file have some instancetype init method

Comment: import swift file like `#import "myproject-Swift.h" ` The class where inherited swift like - class `@interface C :A`